# Why was my answer moved to a new question?

Tags: support, moderation

In [Working titles of Star Wars films?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120637/working-titles-of-star-wars-films) I currently have a deleted answer.

Interestingly enough I didn't answer this question, I answered a question specifically asking regarding Star Wars Episode VIII.

Hence, I have two questions:

1. Why was the question I answered 'merged' and not removed?
2. Why was my answer added on the new question, when it's clearly not answering the new question?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you saying that you tried to answer a different question? I'm pretty sure [my question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120637/working-titles-of-star-wars-films) (where your answer was posted) has not been merged with any other question. Maybe you just posted your answer on the wrong page by accident?

Comment: Precisely what's confusing me. Because the question I originally remember answering was referring to solely the VIII and IX films rather than the whole series. It also didn't refer Blue Harvest

Comment: That's weird. Maybe you just misread my question? (I just confirmed that there haven't been any merges in the last few days.)

Comment: I did consider that possibility, however there was also one more answer on the question, which also only referred to the VIII movie

Comment: Yes, Wad Cheber's answer originally referred only to VII and VIII (though he soon edited it to cover all the films). As the OP, I can confirm that **my question wasn't edited after submission**, and Episodes I-VI were always included in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You must have just got very confused.

As a moderator, I can confirm that **the question where your answer was posted has not been merged with any other**. Your answer only ever appeared in one place, namely on the question you link to: [Working titles of Star Wars films?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120637/working-titles-of-star-wars-films)

As the OP of that question, I can confirm that **the question has not been edited since submission**. It was never asking about only Episodes VIII and IX; it has been in exactly the same form ever since I hit the "Post Your Question" button.

So I don't know how you came to the conclusion that you actually answered a different question. Sorry.

Comment: I do agree it's very weird, and that is is possible for that to have happened. However, I just wanted to make sure since I've seen weirder happen over at Arqade